# Wordpress not resizing images on my production server

Tags: php, wordpress, gd, imagick

I am building a wordpress site, and everything seems to work fine locally, but when I upload it to my production server, images are not resizing.

Sample code:

```
$images     = types_render_field('slideshow', array( "width" => 727, "height" => 500, "url" => "true" ));
```

I am running Wordpress 3.8.1 with php 5.3. I tried installing `php5-imagick` and `php5-gd`, but that didn't seem to solve the problem. I believe the libraries are properly installed, because the output for `phpinfo()` is quite similar, besides some minor version differences that shouldn't be making any difference.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You could check the /wp-content/uploads folder permissions. Trying setting them to 777. If it does the trick, try 755 (more secure).

You could also check your PHP error log, see if you find any message that could help.

Comment: Good ideas, but it didnt work. The permission didnt solve the issue. When you say PHP error log, I assume you mean apache2 `error.log`. There wasnt an information there as well that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. When I copied the local copy to my live server, I also imported the database that I was using locally. Im not sure why, but the images werent working properly, so all I had to do was delete all the images and reupload them from scratch.